# Variables dependent on a variable not assigned (Good Practices)

Tags: python, pseudocode, conventions

Basically put:

```
def function1():
    y = x + 2
    return y

def function2():
    x = 2
    return function1()

function2()
```

When you have multiple functions that depend on other functions and you get assignments after already writing a variable dependent on another one like the y needing the x before it was assigned on the code above.

I know this won't end up giving any errors since func1 is called by func2 so should I just not care and stop obsessing about it?
I feel like this is kinda messy and might get in the way of testing and I keep getting the warnings in the editor which lead me to believe that this is not a good way to go about things.

What would be the best practice in cases like this, or how would you prefer to solve this, I know I could explicitly pass the variable to the function to solve this, but I was wondering if there was a better and more readable way of going through this.

Thanks. :D

Comment: *"I know this won't end up giving any errors"* - I propose trying it rather than guessing. If you don't get an error from this code then you are not running it correctly.

Comment: This *absolutely will give errors*.

Comment: In any case, this is definitely a bad way to organize your programs. Functions should take the data they need as *arguments* and the caller should get the data it needs *as a return value*. Don't rely on mutable, global state, or in this case, assume that Python has dynamic scoping (which it doesn't, and would be a bad way to do this anyway)

Comment: **explicitly passing arguments to functions is the best, most readable way**.

Comment: As a side-note, for a programming language to work like your example code suggests, it would need to have [dynamic scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Dynamic_scope). Almost every non-esoteric programming language has lexical scope, not dynamic scope.

Comment: @kaya3 yeah, and probably for good reason - code that worked like this would be a huge mess. And it doesn't have to be super esoteric, shell languages like bash support dynamic scope. And I've seen a lot of *very* messy shell scripts.

Comment: You're totally right I'm failing to replicate it how I did on a bigger code and I can't figure out why it still works perfectly fine. D:

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I can confirm that LaTeX is a huge mess, indeed ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to reinforce what the comments have said, here is a proper way to write that.  No external dependencies:

```
def function1(x):
    y = x + 2
    return y

def function2():
    x = 2
    return function1(x)

print(function2())
```